# Add validation rule in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

I am using laravel want to add a rule when user submit data. I need to check the value and if all are okay then it will store in database. When user submit a value of text box it will match only for 2 values and if any wrong pass the value then give me the error message. It will match only

**loading and waiting**. like user will pass value like that loading/aba, loading/ppp or waiting/sss, waiting/asd1456. this is correct and store in database.

If user pass sasd/asdasd, 564564/45646546, asdasd/asasas then this give error.

Check only **loading and waiting**. I have added below rule but use add any string after loading and waiting.

```
'loadingwaiting' => 'required|string|in:loading/abcd,loading/qwer,loading/erty,loading/asdf,waiting/eee,waiting/rty,waiting/wes,waiting/dfc,waiting/asd'
```

Before this was decided values but now itsadd any string after loading and waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `regex` validation rule, as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-regex). I didn't test on all cases, but for the ones you provided this should do the job:

`loadingwaiting' => ['required', 'string', 'regex:^(loading|waiting)\/.+$']`

Note that you should use the array representation of validation rules because the regex pattern contains `|` in it, and that would cause it to break.

The regex expression will match any string beginning with loading or waiting ( `(loading|waiting)` ) , that has a slash immediately after ( `\/` , note the escape), and one or more of any character ( `.+` ).